# Calling stored procedure with string output parameter

Tags: c++, sql, c, sql-server, odbc

I want to call a stored procedure in SQL Server 2022 database with string output parameter using ODBC API. Numeric output parameters work fine, but the string ones I can not get to work.

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestStoredProcedure(@inParam VARCHAR(MAX), @outParam VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT) AS
BEGIN
  SET @outParam = @inParam;
END;
```

Application code snippet (error checking omitted):

```
char* pStr = "{call TestStoredProcedure(?, ?)}";
SQLPrepare(hstmt, pStr, (SQLINTEGER)strlen(pStr));

char inParam[10] = "1234";
char outParam[10] = "";

SQLBindParameter(hstmt,
            (SQLUSMALLINT)1,
            SQL_PARAM_INPUT,
            SQL_C_CHAR,
            SQL_LONGVARCHAR,
            (SQLUINTEGER)strlen(inParam),
            0,
            (SQLPOINTER)inParam,
            sizeof(inParam),
            0);

SQLBindParameter(hstmt,
            (SQLUSMALLINT)2,
            SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT,
            SQL_C_CHAR,
            SQL_LONGVARCHAR,
            (SQLUINTEGER)sizeof(outParam),
            0,
            (SQLPOINTER)outParam,
            sizeof(outParam),
            0);

SQLExecute(hstmt); // error
```

The error is:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid parameter 4 (''):  Data
> type 0x23 is a deprecated large object, or LOB, but is marked as output parameter.
> Deprecated types are not supported as output parameters.  Use current large object types instead.

I tried with `VARCHAR(5)`, `CHAR(5)`, `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, but nothing seems to work.

What should be the parameter types in order for this to work and what exactly is the `Invalid parameter 4 ('')`?

Comment: Using `SQL_SS_LENGTH_UNLIMITED` as a value of `ColumnSize` parameter may [help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-api/sqlbindparameter?view=sql-server-ver16#binding-parameters-for-sql-character-types).

Comment: As a side note, is it really likely that your input, and output, values are going to be larger than 8,000 bytes? If not, then consider using a more representative length for your parameters instead of `MAX`.

Comment: @ThomA as stated in the question, I did try with VARCHAR(5) and CHAR(5) but get the same error no matter what I do.

Comment: When/where did you try `varchar(5)` in both the SP's definition *and* the binding *at the same time*? Data type 0x23 is `text`, which *is* a deprecated data type.

Comment: @ThomA changing SQL_LONGVARCHAR to SQL_VARCHAR seems to work for VARCHAR(5).

Comment: SQL_VARCHAR works for VARCHAR(MAX) as well, so apparently the main problem is in the SQL_LONGVARCHAR

Comment: I can't find documentation for it, but I suspect that `SQL_LONGVARCHAR` maps to `text`, which is why you were getting the error. I suspect that `SQL_WLONGVARCHAR` and `SQL_LONGVARBINARY` also map to `ntext` and `image` respectively (which are also both deprecated).

Comment: Probably this part of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-results/data-type-usage?view=sql-server-ver16) is relevant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The output character has to be `SQL_VARCHAR`, not `SQL_LONGVARCHAR`:

```
SQLBindParameter(hstmt,
            (SQLUSMALLINT)2,
            SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT,
            SQL_C_CHAR,
            SQL_VARCHAR,
            (SQLUINTEGER)sizeof(outParam),
            0,
            (SQLPOINTER)outParam,
            sizeof(outParam),
            0);
```